# Powerbuilder: Multiline edit events

Tags: sybase, powerbuilder

I need to enable the command button after the user edit changed the Multi line edit control.

I tried with few EVENT ID , but it didn't work for me.

What is the best way to obtain the edit change event in the Multi line Edit control.

I don't find edit change event MLE control, please help.

Comment: Remember to use tags to your advantage.  The Sybase tag by itself is almost completely unhelpful.  There is a powerbuilder tag, which I've added to your question.

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 events that you can consider in your case:

- `pbm_enchange`: each time the user is typing a character
- `pbm_enmodified`: once the edit is loosing focus, as a global final modification notification

Comment: @user2393425: You're welcome. If it helped you, feel free to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/65088/173356)